# Why is it that !!0 is false and {}+[] is 0 but !!({}+[]) is true?

Tags: javascript

Just tried this in my browser's console:

```
!!0 //=> false
{} + [] //=> 0
!!({} + []) //=> true
```

What's going on here!?

**Edit:** I'm talking about `{} + []`<sup>(object first)</sup> which is different from `[] + {}`<sup>(array first)</sup>, the latter always returns `0`. Spacing (`{}+[]` vs `{} + []`) doesn't seem to matter

Comment: welcome to javascript!

Comment: Something data-type-related?

Comment: or try `[]+[]` and `{}+{}`

Comment: I think you meant "Wat".

Comment: Hi, 0 indicates false .!0 is true which follows negotion policy . !!0 is false as !true is false.

Comment: Try `typeof 0` and `typeof {} + []` - see the difference and judge.

Comment: It is a dupe now to find it

Comment: @nikhil also compare `typeof eval("{}+[]")`, there's something really weird going on.

Comment: @Shel - It is same as `{} + []`

Comment: @nikhil In my browser (Firefox 39), `typeof 0` is "number", `typeof {} + []` is "object", and `typeof eval("{} + []")` is "number". It is not the same.

Comment: Here's an entertaining talk about this problem: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @Shel, `typeof {} + []` is actually the result of `typeof {}` which returns an `object` plus the `[]` which also returns an `object` ... in other words. `eval('{} + []')` is the same as typing `{} + []` in the console

Comment: @tonchis I know, that talk is what piqued my curiousity enough to discover this. This particular quirck isn't mentioned.

Comment: @Shel I've updated my answer. I think I figured it out.

Comment: @epascarello Did you find the dupe yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing `({} + [])` produces the string `[object Object]` which when coerced into a boolean is a true value.

Why it treats it as a string concatenation when wrapped in parentheses and a number when not wrapped, I'm trying to figure out.

**Update:** I think I've figured it out. This trick happens when the code at a global level, i.e. not as an assignment or as an argument. What's probably happening is it's interpreting the `{}` as a block rather than an object.

If you type `{ var x = 4; } +[]` into your console you'll get the same result as `{}+[]`. Where as if you place it inside of a set of parentheses it forces the compiler to interpret the interior as an expression i.e. an `Object` plus an `Array` which produces the string.

My guess is this change is due in part to the change in scope handling due to `let`.

Comment: Awesome! We're halfway there. I've discovered that `{}+{}` is not the same as `({}+{})`, but `[]+[]` and `([]+[])` are the same.

Comment: Re: Edit: `{foo: "bar"}+[]` still returns 0. But wait, `eval('foo:"bar"')` is valid(?????), so I guess you're right. I guess the only way to force an object to be a plain object is to wrap it in parentheses (or assign it, or use it in a comparison, or whatever I haven't thought of)

Comment: @Shel The reason `foo: "bar"` is legal is because you're creating a label called `foo` which you can jump to using `break` or `continue`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxvL34xw/).

Answer (score 1):

```
{} + [] // 0
!!0 // false

({} + []) // [object Object]
!!({} + []) // true

eval("{} + []") // 0
!!eval("{} + []") // false
```

Nothing wrong here!
But there is one really weird thing: if you put `({}+[]) === {}+[]`, the answer is `true`, and if you put `{}+[] === ({}+[])`, the answer is `false`, wtf.

Comment: assigning to a variable (`a = {}+[]`) will also make it an object, as will (apparently) the `===` operator. `({}+[]) === eval("{}+[]")` gives the expected `false`

Answer (score -2):

That's wrong, `{} + []` is not `0`:

```js
alert({} + []);
```

**Update:** not commutative behaviour (Node shell):

```
// as expected
{} + [] // '[object Object]'
[] + {} // '[object Object]'

// however
eval("{} + []") // 0
eval("[] + {}") // '[object Object]'
```

Comment: Open your console and just type `{} + []`

Comment: `node -e 'console.log({} + [])'` // return [object Object]

Comment: Again, you're calling it in a function. Remove the function entirely.

Comment: The same result: `> {} + []` // '[object Object]'

Comment: try `alert(eval("{} + []"))`

Comment: What version of node are you running? If I open node v0.12.3 then type in `{} + []` I get `0`

Comment: I just tried and you're right. Something changed in V8 between Node version 0.11.0 and 0.12.0.